# How to add an attribute programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to add an attribute to products, and I want to do this programmatically. So I added a mysql-install-0.1.0.php to a module of mine, and I added this (inspired from existing examples) :

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'collection', array(
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'Collection',
        'input'             => 'text',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => '',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'           => false,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => false,
        'default'           => '',
        'searchable'        => false,
        'filterable'        => false,
        'comparable'        => false,
        'visible_on_front'  => false,
        'unique'            => false,
        'apply_to'          => '',
        'is_configurable'   => false
    ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Syntax seems OK, but when it comes to execute this part of the code, here is the problem :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()
>   in
>   /home/frleq/Dev/projets/AVIP/WORKSPACE/avip_magento/app/code/local/Smile/Magentaho/sql/magentaho_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
>   on line 7

Do you see what's wrong? Code isn't so complicated, and it is inspired from existing and worling ones...

Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are using the wrong setup class. Check your setup class declaration in config.xml. You are using `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`. Try `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` instead.

Comment: That's right, I forgot to mention the Setup class in config.xml:


                <setup>
                   <module>Company_Module</module>
                   <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>

Thanks a lot Anders

Comment: Don't! Use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` instead of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` regarding Products/Catalog attributes or their additional attributes **won't** be set (i.e. "is_searchable", "is_visible_on_front" etc.) because of the `_prepareValues()` method in the setup class.

Comment: What if you need to use both?

Comment: @surfeur190, in your install script, use $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute(...

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use product-related options (filterable, searchable etc.), you should use **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup** class.

In latest versions of Magento you should use **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup** class.

Comment: Best answer! To be able to set the product specific settings like visible_on_front, you'll need to use a Mage_Catalog_* setup class.